# Covering a rectangle with polyomino's copies

Tags: geometry

Task:
You're given 3 separate polyominoes, which you can see on the left, see img. #1.
You must find the placement for copies of each one polyomino, so they would cover a rectangle of max area.
To simplify it - on the right, you can see an example. A 13-omino's copies have been put in such an arrangement, that they cover the max area rectangle that they can. It's copies CAN be arranged in multiple ways, but a bigger area rectangle CAN'T be achieved.

Image #1 - https://gyazo.com/bc04ade896d20738d43130b997787eb5

Rules:
To copy a polyomino, you can:

- Rotate it
- Make a reflection of it
- or both.

*Two polyominoes can't cover each other.
There is no limit on how many times you can copy a polyomino.
Remember to not combine the 3 given polyominoes - they are as 3 separate tasks with the same rules.*

Comment: Welcome to MSE, it is recommended on this iste to share your own attempts for solving the problem, os that others can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Personal attempt at 1st polyomino: https://gyazo.com/1e9bc86639b9204ae3941005a5647345
Covers a rectangle with an area of 21

Comment: It might be better to edit this into your question, no?